# Attaching an interrupt to a member function

Tags: c++, beginner, object-oriented, arduino, device-driver

I am making my own optical encoders. Each of them follows the exact same structure, so I figured I'd lump all the encoder processing in a class, `StepCounter`. However, when I directly attach an interrupt to a member function, I get

```
cannot convert 'StepCounter::step' from type 'void (StepCounter::)()' to type 'void (*)()'
```

Fair enough, a member method is different than a global method (however, maybe I can somehow cast it to a `void(*)()` by providing `this`?). So, I made the following solution (note: 18, 19 and 22, 23 are pin numbers, so assume that the naming convention makes any sense there):

```
class StepCounter {
  public:
    StepCounter(int pinInterrupt, int pinSecond, void (*wrapperFcn)(void)) :
      pinInterrupt(pinInterrupt),
      pinSecond(pinSecond) {
      pinMode(pinInterrupt, INPUT);
      pinMode(pinSecond, INPUT);
      stateSecond = digitalRead(pinSecond);
      attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(pinInterrupt), wrapperFcn, CHANGE);
    };

    volatile int distance = 0;

    void step() {
      int newSecond = digitalRead(pinSecond);
      int stateXOR = digitalRead(pinInterrupt);
      // Direction is stateXOR * (stateSecond==newSecond)
      // if we take (-1,1) rather than (0,1) for (true,false)
      int  multiplier = (stateXOR == HIGH) ? -1 : 1;
      if (stateSecond == newSecond) {
        distance -= multiplier;
      } else {
        distance += multiplier;
      }
      stateSecond = newSecond;
    }

  private:
    const int pinInterrupt;
    const int pinSecond;
    volatile int stateSecond;

};

void interrupt1822(); // Forward declaration
void interrupt1923();

StepCounter stepCounter1822(18,22,interrupt1822),
            stepCounter1923(19,23,interrupt1923);

void interrupt1822() {
  stepCounter1822.step();
};
void interrupt1923() {
  stepCounter1923.step();
};
```

But, in all honesty, this looks rather clumsy with a bunch of forward declarations. And, although there is only so many interrupt pins on an Arduino, I still feel that copy-pasting so many things is something that should usually be avoided in programming.

Furthermore, I'm wondering whether there is any faster way of doing my `step()` function; since it's an interrupt service routine that I expect to be called a lot, I'd like it to be as fast as possible.

Answer (score 4):

Yes; the key issue here is that you are dynamically determining values that can be determined statically.

Luckily, you are working in a language with extensive static analysis capabilities (template metaprogramming), so let's use that!  (This sounds more complicated than it is.)

Also: I'm not sure why you determine the sign of `multiplier` separately from whether you should add or subtract it from `distance`.  If statements are slow, because the processor needs to predict the correct branch (at best) or flush the pipeline (at worst).   So I've removed that; hopefully it will get optimized into a `setcc` or similar.  (I should also mention I'm not familiar with Arduino processors; it is entirely possible these changes are irrelevant.)

Finally, since you're working in C++, you really should use constructors or uniform initializers, rather than assignments.  Yes, a decent compiler will optimize away the temporary, but it is always better to be easy on your poor compiler.

```
template<int const pinIndex, int const pinIndex2>
void interrupt(void)
{
    volatile static int pinState(digitalRead(pinIndex2)), distance(0);
    int const newState(digitalRead(pinIndex2)), multiplier(((HIGH == digitalRead(pinIndex)) ^ (newState == pinState)) ? -1 : 1);
    distance += multiplier;
    pinState = newState;
}

template<int const pinIndex, int const pinIndex2>
void registerInterrupt(void)
{
    pinMode(pinIndex, INPUT);
    pinMode(pinIndex2, INPUT);
    attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(pinIndex), &interrupt<pinIndex, pinIndex2>, CHANGE);
}
void registerInterrupts(void)
{
    registerInterrupt<18, 22>(void);
    registerInterrupt<19, 23>(void);
}
```

If you're confused how this holds state, look at the static variables.  These also might slow the interrupt down; if so, make them static members of a templated struct, like so:

```
template<int const pinIndex, int const pinIndex2>
struct interruptData
{
    volatile static int pinState(digitalRead(pinIndex2)), distance(0);
}
```

Then change the references inside the interrupt.

Beyond this, I don't see a way to improve your interrupt.  It's pretty bare-bones to begin with.

Comment: Thanks. Quite a clever approach to start with. However, I'm still not clear on how it holds state - how do I even access `distance`? Something like `interrupt<19,23>.distance` doesn't work.

Comment: Static variables are local variables that the compiler guarantees will be initialized exactly once, in a thread-safe, reentrant manner.  See en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration#Static_local_variables  So basically I'm hardcoding the members of the StepCounter object into the interrupt.

Comment: I didn't realize you'll need access to distance outside the interrupt; you can't do it as written, but if you use the "static member of a struct" alternative I mentioned, you can.